# How to connect to concrete database in docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker-compose

I have next setup of `docker-compose.yaml`

```
name: test-app-to-delete

services:
  mongo:
    image: mongo
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mongo
    volumes:
      - db:/data/db:rw
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: 'user'
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'password'
      MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE: 'db-name'

  mongo-express:
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    networks:
      - mongo
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: user
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: password
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_URL: mongodb://user:password@mongo:27017/db-name

networks:
  mongo:

volumes:
  db:
```

So issue become a problem when I'm adding `db-name` to this configuration.

Errors:

```
Could not connect to database using connectionString: 
mongodb://user:password@mongo:27017/db-name
```

Just for note: I'm recreated database before run this configuration, so issue not in cached data.

Comment: 1) not reproducible, please post a complete docker-compose.

Comment: Full docker file published, and I'm not using k8s

Comment: please try `mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/db-name?authSource=admin` instead of your current connection string

Comment: And make sure to use `base64` converted values for username and password

Comment: `?authSource=admin` helped! Thank you folks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `mongodb://user:password@localhost:27017/db-name?authSource=admin` instead of your current connection string.
And make sure to use `base64` converted values for `username` and `password`